# Comparing a date and getting result of records having further dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql for database connectivity. I am filtering records in database on date basis using sql query which consists of function `convert(varchar(100),column name,106)`. I am comparing it with date having `dd/MMM/yyyy` format. As a result I get records of next all the dates.

Example: If I try to filter the table by 01/June/2017 then inspite of having records of that date, I get records of next all the dates. I am not able to get records of 01/June/2017.

I have used greater than or equal to expression.

Comment: Could you please post your SQL as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to convert it to this yyyymmdd number format and do the comparison as below:

```
select convert(int,convert(varchar(10),[your column],112))

20170529
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert your dates into any format (=strings) when doing comparison. Always use the date (or datetime etc) format. That way you will be comparing the actual values, not string or numeric comparison. Here the problem is that format 106 is `dd mon yyyy` so it will never match your date because it's a string `dd/MMM/yyyy` but you will get any dates starting with `02` anyhow, for example `02/Jan/1990`, because in alphabetical order that will come after your given date.